# Trying to AND all elements in a list of lists

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a new list of elements by ANDing the lists in my list of lists.

I've tried putting the list in a while loop with a counter representing the length of the list, and doing

```
values = values[counter] && values [counter + 1]
```

but for some reason this doesn't give me the correct result

my goal is this in a nutshell:

```
values = [["B", "W"],["C","W"]]
...
result = ["W"]
```

Comment: Ruby has 3 "ands": the binary operator `&` (intersection for arrays), the boolean operator `&&` and the control-flow operator `and`. In certain situations they may work alike, buy their purpose is entirely different.

Answer (score 3):

```
[["B", "W"], ["C", "W"]].reduce([], :&)
  #=> ["W"]

[["B", "W", "A"], ["A", "C", "W"], ["W", "E", "A"]].reduce([], :&)
  #=> ["W", "A"]
```

See [Enumerable#reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) and [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-26). `arr.reduce([], :&)` is shorthand for:

```
arr.reduce([]) { |intersection, a| intersection & a }
```

`reduce` is assigned an initial value `[]` in case its receiver is an empty array.

Comment: you're amazing :)

Comment: You can also pass an initial value as the first argument, i.e. `reduce([], :&)`. This can be useful if your `values` array happens to be empty (`[].reduce(:&)` would return `nil`).